# Trying to make an Image pop up when I hover on a Title

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm trying to make an image show up when I hover over a title `<h1>` tag.

This is my CSS so far:

```
    .certificate h1{
            text-align:left;
        }

    .certificate:hover, .certificate:hover img{
        visibility:visible;
        z-index:100;
    }

    .certificate img{
        visibility:hidden;
        position:absolute;
    }
```

Below is my HTML too

```
<div class="certificate">
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
<div class="certificate">
    <img src="./images/image.jpg">
</div>
```

For some reason my image still desnt show up. Am I checking hover on the right tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the hovering `.certificate` doesn't have the image. Put both of them in the same container. Also, since the only thing in the `.container` with image has the image with `position: absolute`, it doesn't give any `:hover` space. So, technically, you can't hover the image's parent.

```css
.certificate h1 {
  text-align: left;
}
.certificate:hover img {
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 100;
}
.certificate img {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="certificate">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```